# install jdk-7u71-nb-8_0_2-linux-i586.sh

Tags: software-installation, jdk, ide

I have downloaded JDK 7u71 with NetBeans 8.0.2 from http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/java/jdk-7-netbeans-download-432126.html.
I want to know how to install jdk-7u71-nb-8_0_2-linux-i586.sh on ubuntu. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

TO  install .SH file :-

open terminal :-

go to folder you have downloaded (considering in download folder ) :-

```
cd Downloads/
```

make .sh file executable by :-

```
   chmod +x 'yourfile.sh'
```

**ie:**        `chmod +x netbeans.sh`

Or right click on **.sh** file **>>** properties **>>** permission **>>** allow to execute

NOW :- run

```
./yourfile.sh
```

**ie:** `./netbeans.sh`